# Finding a formula for shortlex ordered sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Consider the integers $0...2^n-1$ for some $n \geq 0$, ordered:

1. by the number of 1 bits in their binary representation, then
2. in *reverse* lexicographic order according to their *reversed* binary representation.

Is there a formula for this sequence?

To be clear, here is a table listing the sequences for $n = 2...6$. Note that the each binary string is listed in reverse (the least-significant bit is the leftmost character).

```
               Reverse                  Reverse
Index  Decimal  Binary | Index  Decimal  Binary
------[ n = 2 ]------- | ------[ n = 6 ]-------
    0        0      00 |     0        0  000000
    1        1      10 |     1        1  100000
    2        2      01 |     2        2  010000
    3        3      11 |     3        4  001000
                       |     4        8  000100
------[ n = 3 ]------- |     5       16  000010
    0        0     000 |     6       32  000001
    1        1     100 |     7        3  110000
    2        2     010 |     8        5  101000
    3        4     001 |     9        9  100100
    4        3     110 |    10       17  100010
    5        5     101 |    11       33  100001
    6        6     011 |    12        6  011000
    7        7     111 |    13       10  010100
                       |    14       18  010010
------[ n = 4 ]------- |    15       34  010001
    0        0    0000 |    16       12  001100
    1        1    1000 |    17       20  001010
    2        2    0100 |    18       36  001001
    3        4    0010 |    19       24  000110
    4        8    0001 |    20       40  000101
    5        3    1100 |    21       48  000011
    6        5    1010 |    22        7  111000
    7        9    1001 |    23       11  110100
    8        6    0110 |    24       19  110010
    9       10    0101 |    25       35  110001
   10       12    0011 |    26       13  101100
   11        7    1110 |    27       21  101010
   12       11    1101 |    28       37  101001
   13       13    1011 |    29       25  100110
   14       14    0111 |    30       41  100101
   15       15    1111 |    31       49  100011
                       |    32       14  011100
------[ n = 5 ]------- |    33       22  011010
    0        0   00000 |    34       38  011001
    1        1   10000 |    35       26  010110
    2        2   01000 |    36       42  010101
    3        4   00100 |    37       50  010011
    4        8   00010 |    38       28  001110
    5       16   00001 |    39       44  001101
    6        3   11000 |    40       52  001011
    7        5   10100 |    41       56  000111
    8        9   10010 |    42       15  111100
    9       17   10001 |    43       23  111010
   10        6   01100 |    44       39  111001
   11       10   01010 |    45       27  110110
   12       18   01001 |    46       43  110101
   13       12   00110 |    47       51  110011
   14       20   00101 |    48       29  101110
   15       24   00011 |    49       45  101101
   16        7   11100 |    50       53  101011
   17       11   11010 |    51       57  100111
   18       19   11001 |    52       30  011110
   19       13   10110 |    53       46  011101
   20       21   10101 |    54       54  011011
   21       25   10011 |    55       58  010111
   22       14   01110 |    56       60  001111
   23       22   01101 |    57       31  111110
   24       26   01011 |    58       47  111101
   25       28   00111 |    59       55  111011
   26       15   11110 |    60       59  110111
   27       23   11101 |    61       61  101111
   28       27   11011 |    62       62  011111
   29       29   10111 |    63       63  111111
   30       30   01111 |                       
   31       31   11111 |
```

Basically, I'm looking for an elementary formula from the first column ("Index") to the second column ("Decimal") for any given $n$, if possible.

Now, it's pretty straightforward to produce this sequence algorithmically. Obviously one way would be to simply sort $0...2^n-1$ with shortlex ordering. Another way would be to take the subsequence of numbers with cardinality (bit count) $k$ and generate the subsequence of numbers with cardinality $k + 1$, and iterate this until the whole sequence is generated. But for curiosity's sake, I was just wondering if there was a formula that could generate it more directly.

Comment: Your lists do not satisfy your requirements. For example, 10010 and 01100 both have 2 1-bits, but lexographically, 01100 should precede 10010, not follow it.

Comment: @martycohen Thank you. I have corrected the description of the sort order and updated the tables. The english explanation of the order is a little more complicated now, but the order of the sequences (column 2) are unchanged.